# configuring a JNDI Datasource from JBOSS 4.2.3 in a Spring application

Tags: java, spring, jboss

this is my  mysql-ds.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
      <jndi-name>jdbc/DefaultDS</jndi-name>
      <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usuarios</connection-url>
      <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
      <user-name>root</user-name>
      <password>da</password>
      <valid-connection-checker-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLValidConnectionChecker</valid-connection-checker-class-name>
      <metadata>
    <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
    </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

and this is my  bean in context.xml

```
<beans>
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">   
    <property name="jndiName">  
        <value>jdbc/DefaultDS</value>  
    </property>  
</bean>
```

this is the correct way? this error occurs when i run my junit Test

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

this is my first question in this site thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need "java:jdbc/DefaultDS"

So the bean definition would look like:

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">   
    <property name="jndiName">  
        <value>java:jdbc/DefaultDS</value>  
    </property>  
</bean>
```

Comment: Adding the resourceRef property should fix the problem also.

<property name="resourceRef" value="true" />

This tell the bean to look up the DS in the JEE container